# Check keystore alias and KeyStore Certificate information name inside the application

Tags: android, apk, android-keystore

I have signed my android application with my generated keystore certificate is it possible inside my java code to check the unique information of keystore certificate using which i have generated or exported my apk file.

Comment: Why would you like to do that? And no, I doubt that this is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're trying to figure out *which* keystore you originally signed your app with. There's no way I know of that you can extract the information.

However, if you have multiple keystores that you likely signed it with around, you can sign the app again with each and try to install it over the top of the existing one. The right key will let you install it, the wrong one will give you an error. I don't recall if you have to increment the version number or not, though.